# How to change the signature ( aka "magic numbers") of the file?

Tags: php, file-upload, operating-system, file-format, file-type

In my site i used **exif_imagetype** function while uploading an image. I thought it is secure function to neglect other files to be uploaded. But i read an article that if we change the signature of the file then we can upload what ever file we need. i tried to get information to change te file signature in net stil i cant find it..

```
if (! exif_imagetype($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])) 
{
    echo "File is not an image"; 
}
```

Any one please help me to change the signature of the file..I need to test those files in my site while i hosted in local network.

Comment: check both file extension and MIME type, and allow only `.php` extension to execute on your server.

Comment: I need to change the signature of the file... so please say where the signature will be located because i need to edit it and check

Answer (score 2):

you can find the list of common file magic numbers in this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29).

to change magic numbers takes a very simply process. you can use a hex editor to change the first few bytes of a file. you can write your self a program that change these values and so on.

Mime type of the file is determined by reading these magic numbers.